# Why does Entity Framework generate two "ORDER BY" clauses?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE "ADMIN"."TABLETEST" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOTE" NUMBER
)
```

How I use my table with Entity Framework:

```
var s = entities.TABLETESTs.OrderByDescending(r => r.NOTE).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

The request generated with this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
         "Extent1"."NOTE" AS "NOTE"
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
              "Extent1"."NOTE" AS "NOTE",  
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."NOTE" DESC) AS "row_number"
          FROM 
              (SELECT 
                   "TABLETEST"."ID" AS "ID", 
                   "TABLETEST"."NOTE" AS "NOTE"
               FROM 
                   "ADMIN"."TABLETEST" "TABLETEST") "Extent1"
          )  "Extent1"
    WHERE 
        ("Extent1"."row_number" > 10)
    ORDER BY 
        "Extent1"."NOTE" DESC
)
WHERE 
    (ROWNUM <= (10) )
```

If you read this last request you can find that it contains two `ORDER BY "Extent1"."NOTE" DESC`; why does Entity Framework generate two "order by" clauses, is it necessary? Because if I omit the second 'order by' my request becomes much faster and it gives the same result as with both "order by"

Comment: That's the reason why I don't like to use such frameworks...

Comment: The first order by is applied to the row_number window function and is unrelated to the order by of the result set. The reason for the row_number is to get a sequential order withing a partition of data so that your skip() statement can work as expected. Taking out the skip would be the same as removing the first order by.

Comment: but when i remove the OrderByDescending(), it crashes when i call ToList() it says that skip is only supported for sorted input

Comment: Looks like the inner one is to apply the offset and the outer one is for the limit. The inner set is ordered due to the analytic `row_number()` expression but I'm not sure whether that is documented or guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: It's also unfortunate that the framework uses outdated sql syntax for oracle, why not simply `SELECT ID, NOTE FROM "ADMIN"."TABLETEST" ORDER BY NOTE OFFEST 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS`...

Comment: definitely true but my request are a lot more complexe than this example, it depends on a lot of parameters (over 30 possible combinations of filters + 15 ways of sorting + a very flexible pagination + lot of other stuff of getting the data ...) to construct the final request with EF. it is hard to change what it is already been done, all i can do unfortunately is to read the final request and do some fixes before send it to the DB

Comment: @Radagast81, Row Limits and Row Offsets was introduced in Oracle 12.1, I would not consider `WHERE ROWNUM < ...` as being "outdated".